# How to create a sequence of threads to execute a task in the order they are started?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm not from computer science background. Please point to me the right resources for the following. Here is what I'm doing in C++/CLI with windows forms.

```
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    for (i=0; i < n ;i++){ 
        array<UInt32>^ Buffer = gcnew array<UInt32>(numericTextBox2->IntValue); 

        /* Some time consuming process. Takes approximately 8 to 10 seconds 
        and fills Buffer.*/

        Thread^ executerThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &Form1::Task));
        executerThread.Start((Object^)Buffer)   
    }
}

private: void Task(Object^ i)
{   
    array<UInt32>^ Buffer = (array<UInt32>^)i;
    mut->WaitOne();

    /* Here I send the Buffer as a stream of integers through the hardware driver. 
    This stream is sent out by the hardware(with built in internal clock) at 
    a fixed frequency of one integer every micro second. */

    mut->ReleaseMutex();     
    return    
}
```

I need all the threads to run Task() function in the order they are started as if the function Task() is called inside the loop. I think I'll have a synchronization problem if my Buffers are very small. If my arrays are very big and the time taken to prepare them is larger than time to execute Task, the program serves my purpose as the threads execute Task() in a sequence as they are called. In this case there are utmost two threads(One running the proceedure and the other waiting for the resource). But if my arrays are very short and the Task execution time is long (uncertain because this involves the hardware driver), then there are multiple threads waiting for the resource. I don't know if the tasks are executed in the order they are started. I think its up to the OS to execute these according to its rules. So I need a method or way of making these threads to execute in the order they are started.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you format your code?

Comment: Why do tasks need to run in the "order they are started" and what does that mean exactly?  Can tasks run in parallel?  Is it the order of results that is important?

Comment: The tasks are done on the same hardware. Therefore they cannot be parallel. I should do a sequence of jobs on the hardware to get the desired result. Yes, the order of results that is important.

Comment: Sounds like you want a pipeline. Think of it like an assembly line. Each thread would have a specific job to do and a concurrent queue. Jobs are added to its queue and the thread handles jobs in order. It might also be a match for the consumer/producer paradigm. I can't give a real answer because I don't understand your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve this is with a queue of futures.  On the UI side, spin up an asynchronous task to fill each buffer.  Then, launch a final asynchronous task to wait on the results and pass them to the driver.  Something like the following:

```
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    std::queue<std::future<std::vector<uint32_t>>> items;

    for (i=0; i < n ;i++){ 
        items.push(std::async(std::launch::async, [i] { return CreateBuffer(i); });
    }

    complete_ = std::async(
        std::launch::async,
        [items_ = std::move(items)]
        { 
            while (!items_.empty())
            {
                SendBufferToDriver(items_.front().get());
                items_.pop();
            }
        });
}
```

This will pre-process all the arrays in parallel and then send them to the driver in order.  Since everything is done asynchronously, this will also avoid blocking your UI thread during processing.

**Complications:**

Please keep in mind that this is just a sketch.  You'll also have to consider how to cancel/terminate this process if the user closes the window before all data is sent to the driver.  If this is an ongoing process where the user can click the button multiple times to add more data over time, then the solution is a little more complex.  The basic idea is the same, but you'll probably want a `bounded buffer` instead of a simple queue, and it will have to move out of function scope.

**No std::future?**

If you're stuck on an older compiler without C++11 support, you can accomplish the same thing using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>`.  The interface is similar to `std::async` / `std::future`.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition: You can use linked lists with mutex or queues.

1. Linked list(or vectors? Sorry I'm used to `C`):

   - In the first loop, do some work that generates the "array", appending new integers at the end of the list.
   - The process (thread) that deals with those integers pull elements from the head of the list
2. Queues:
   Well, queues operate more or less the same as described here above, but a lot of process is being already done by the queue library you choose

Comment: Well I cannot use linked lists as the driver function takes a completed array as the argument and spits out the contents of the array at a fixed frequency.